# I have a class to represent integers and I want to differentiate between lbs and kg how do I do this?

Tags: c++

I'm thinking of creating a class for lbs and a separate class for kg which both inherit from integer but don't add anything to them.  This would allow the compiler to verify the right units are passed to functions.

Is this the best approach or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You could consider [Boost.Units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_units.html#boost_units.Introduction).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would have a class called `Mass` or something similar, and have methods that would return the object's value in one unit or another.

```
class Mass
{
public:
  Mass()
    : mMassKG(0) {}
  ~Mass() {}

  int kilograms() const { return mMassKG; }
  int pounds() const { return mMassKG * 2.2; }

  void setKilograms(int kg) { mMassKG = kg; }
  void setPounds(int lbs) { mMassKG = lbs / 2.2; }

private:
  int mMassKG;
};
```

Comment: This is asymmetric, in the sense that you can get in both units, but you can't set in both units.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth True, but I meant it more as a notional example than a functional class.  I've added setters for symmetry.  I would also say that using an integer number of kg as the internal representation is not the best choice if you're primarily storing integer values of pounds.

Comment: `mass1.setKilograms(mass2.pounds())` is what the OP wants to disallow.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create one class that gets an integer (setter) and returns getKg or getLbs methods?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give an example of the kinds of function you need. Depending on what you need, you might be better off making separate method calls for lbs and kgs such as

```
public void doXlbs() {
    ...
}
```

and

```
public void doXkgs() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thoroughly untested, but something like this could to the trick and provide reasonable type safety:

```
template<typename T>
class Unit
{
public:
   explicit Unit(float size) : m_size(size) {}
   float size() const { return m_size; }
   Unit operator += (Unit rhs) { m_size += rhs.size();  return *this; }
private:
   float m_size;
};

template<typename T>
Unit<T> operator+ (Unit<T> lhs, Unit<T> rhs) 
{
   return lhs += rhs;
}
// Plus more useful operators that you need...

struct Kg {};
struct Lb {};

typedef Unit<Kg> Kilograms;
typedef Unit<Lb> Pounds;

Kilograms lbToKg(Pounds lb)
{
   return Kilograms(lb.size() / 2.2);
}

Pounds kgToLb(Kilograms kg)
{
   return Pounds(kg.size() * 2.2);
}
```